# How to i write a react code to display all the locality in a pincode when we type pincode in text box?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need a react code API is given below.
https://api2-4ofagodxfq-uc.a.run.app/locality?stateName=KARNATAKA&districtName=BANGALORE&pinCode=560001

Here when we type 560001 in the text box it should hit the above API, taking value(560001) from the textbox and assigning it to a variable
eg:

```
axios.get(`https://api2-4ofagodxfq-uc.a.run.app/locality?stateName=KARNATAKA&districtName=BANGALORE&pinCode=${pincode}`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [locations, setLocations] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
     if(value === "") return;

     let response = await axios.get(`https://api2-4ofagodxfq-uc.a.run.app/locality?stateName=KARNATAKA&districtName=BANGALORE&pinCode=${value}`);
     if(response.status === 200) setLocations(response.data);
  }

  return <div>
    <input type="text" onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}/>
    <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}></button>
    {locations.map((location, index) => {
       return <p key={index}>{location}</p>
    })}
  </div>
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you Zeeshan, The above code will return objects on console. I need all the places(locaities) to print on the same screen below submit

Comment: Answer Updated.

Comment: Thnks Zeeshan its throwing an error-TypeError: locations.map is not a function

Comment: Answer Updated.

Comment: which coarse do you prefer

Answer (score 0):

Here is my demo on CodePen:

`[[Codepen](https://codepen.io/DoanThanhNhan/pen/YzXyMLX)`
[Click here](https://codepen.io/DoanThanhNhan/pen/YzXyMLX)